# Drawing a shaded region with implicit functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

basically the problem is the same as in a question i previously asked: [Draw shaded region using tikz and pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699986/draw-shaded-region-using-tikz-and-pgfplots)

Now the problem is that the region i want to draw is more complicated, mainly because of the functions involved:
[image]

This is what i want to obtain, but i don't know how to change the code in the answer in order to draw the graph showed in the image, also because tikz does not really get along with sqrt function. Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[->] (-1.2,0)--(1.2,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.2)--(0,1.2) node[above] () {$y$};
        \draw (0,0) circle(.5);
        \draw[blue] (0,.5) circle(.5);
        \draw (0,0) circle(1);
        \filldraw[fill=orange,draw=blue] (.43,.25) arc(30:90:.5)--(0,1);
        \filldraw[fill=orange,draw=blue] (.43,.25) arc(-30:90:.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**SOME EXPLICATION**: With the first line of the fill code You have this:

[image]

With the second line You have this:

[image]

With both line You have the proposed picture in my answer.

**COMPLETE PICTURE AND CODE**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[gray!20,step=.5] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
        \draw[->] (-1.2,0)--(1.2,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.2)--(0,1.2) node[above] () {$y$};
        \draw[red] (0,0) circle(.5);
        \draw[blue,name=C2] (0,.5) circle(.5);
        \draw (0,0) circle(1);
        \node[right] at (.43,.25) (a) {A};
        \filldraw[fill=orange,draw=blue] (.43,.25) arc(30:90:.5)--(0,1); 
        \filldraw[fill=orange,draw=blue] (.43,.25) arc(-30:90:.5);
        \node at (1.5,1) () {$x^2+y^2=1$};
        \node[blue] at (1.5,.5) () {$x^2+(y-\frac12)^2=\frac14$};
        \node[red] at (1.5,-.5) () {$x^2+y^2=\frac14$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! But i have two questions: what do the commands `arc(30:90:.5)` and `arc(-30:90:.5)` do? And how can i add a legend so i can add the equation of the circles?

Comment: @Davide I add some explication in the answer.

Comment: @Davide With the first arc code You draw the arc from A to (0,.5), with the second arc code You draw the arc from A to (0,1).

Comment: Thanks again, now i've understand it <3